# How to detect auto-boxing and auto-unboxing in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, profiling, primitive-types, autoboxing

I'm working on a fairly low-level Kotlin JVM library that deals a lot with `Byte`s and `ByteArrays`. As I'm dealing with large volumes of data, keeping performance of individual operations high is important. I would like to find out if (and where) the JVM is busy with Auto-Boxing and Auto-Unboxing of primitive `byte` into wrapper `Byte` and back. With Kotlin, the compiler hides the syntactic difference between `byte` and `Byte`, which makes this job even harder.

Profilers like JVisualVM do not show auto-boxing and auto-unboxing as individual operations, they just attribute the time it takes to execute them to the parent method as "self time" which isn't helpful in this case.

What are my options to find out if/where auto-boxing and auto-unboxing occur?

Comment: I guess we need to look for `Byte.valueOf(B)` and `Byte.byteValue()` methods (?). Although, if you try to measure the time required for these operations then I guess it is too small. I would assume the bigger problem is additional heap allocations for boxed bytes. But you won't be able to measure it this way.

Comment: Also, arrays/collections are probably much bigger problem than (un)boxing of individual bytes. You should be able to find them easily by searching for: `Array<Byte>`, `List<Byte>`, etc.

Comment: @broot Good idea with the "valueOf(...)" calls; I might be able to set up my profiler to sniff those out specifically. What about things like Iterator<Byte>? That boxes the value as well, right?

Comment: If you have any kind of generic collection like `Array<Byte>`, `List<Byte>`, `Iterator<Byte>`, you read items from it and they are being unboxed, then it most probably go through `Byte.byteValue()`. If you add new items to a such collection, it will go through `Byte.valueOf(B)`. You should definitely verify this assumption, but I believe it should be true.